# Help with induction proof over $x$ (a positive integer)

Tags: summation, induction

Let $x$ be a positive integer, $n$ a natural number such that $3 \leq x<n$. Prove using induction over $x$ that $ \sum_{k=x-2}^{n-1} k(k-1) \cdot\cdot\cdot (k-x+3) = \frac{n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-x+2)}{x-1}$. (I've already made the proof for $n$)

I use induction over $x-1$ so that it doesn't bother the $n$ limit when I get into the induction step. The inductive hypothesis would be $$ \sum_{k=x-3}^{n-1} k(k-1) \cdot\cdot\cdot (k-x+4) = \frac{n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-x+3)}{x-2}.$$
The sum with $x-1$(hypothesis) has one more addend but each addend has one multiplicand less. The problem is that I don´t see where I should use the inductive hypothesis because it increases in a different order.
If you can help me thank you very much.